# How do I kill PIDs running on multiple Apache Tomcat Instances

Tags: apache, centos6

I am installing Esri's Geoportal Server on CentOS 6.  In order to deploy the application a .war file needs to be deployed in the tomcat webapps folder.  My problem is that I have 3 instances of Tomcat on this box.  Apache Tomcat 5, 6, and 7...I am currently unable to stop any of the services.  And when querying the PID, all instances are identical..I would ultimately like to kill PIDs for 5 and 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like script which you have created for tomcat startup creates a lock/pid file at a specific location.

That PID file location will contain process ID.

You need to have unique PID & Lock files for each of the service instances script.